# how to find how many times given value repeating in pandas dataseries if dataseries contains list of string values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Example 1:
let suppose we have **record data series**

```
record      
['ABC' ,'GHI']     
['ABC' , 'XYZ']     
['XYZ','PQR']
```

if I want to calculate how many times each value is repeating from record data-series like

```
 value       Count
 'ABC'           2
 'XYZ'           2
 'GHI'           1
 'PQR'           1
```

In the record series, 'ABC'  and 'XYZ' are repeating for 2 times.
'GHI'  and  'PQR'   repeating for 1 times.

Example 2:

below is the new dataframe.

```
            teams
0   ['Australia', 'Sri Lanka']
1   ['Australia', 'Sri Lanka']
2   ['Australia', 'Sri Lanka']
3   ['Ireland', 'Hong Kong']
4   ['Zimbabwe', 'India']
... ...
1412    ['Pakistan', 'Sri Lanka']
1413    ['Bangladesh', 'India']
1414    ['United Arab Emirates', 'Netherlands']
1415    ['Sri Lanka', 'Australia']
1416    ['Sri Lanka', 'Australia']
```

Now if I apply

```
print(new_df.explode('teams').value_counts())
```

it gives me

```
       teams                        
['England', 'Pakistan']          29
['Australia', 'Pakistan']        26
['England', 'Australia']         25
['Australia', 'India']           24
['England', 'West Indies']       23
          ...                    ..
['Namibia', 'Sierra Leone']       1
['Namibia', 'Scotland']           1
['Namibia', 'Oman']               1
['Mozambique', 'Rwanda']          1
['Afghanistan', 'Bangladesh']     1
Length: 399, dtype: int64
```

But I want

```
team       occurrence of team
India           ?
England         ?
Australia       ?
 ...            ...
```

I want the occurrence of each team from the dataframe.

How to perform this task?

Comment: The type of record is list?

Comment: record is dataseries and it contains data list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas-series-value-counts)

On Series:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series({0: ['ABC', 'GHI'],
               1: ['ABC', 'XYZ'],
               2: ['XYZ', 'PQR']})

r = s.explode().value_counts()
print(r)
```

```
XYZ    2
ABC    2
GHI    1
PQR    1
dtype: int64
```

---

On DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'record': {0: ['ABC', 'GHI'],
                              1: ['ABC', 'XYZ'],
                              2: ['XYZ', 'PQR']}})

r = df.explode('record')['record'].value_counts()
print(r)
```

```
XYZ    2
ABC    2
GHI    1
PQR    1
Name: record, dtype: int64
```

Comment: It works fine for example 1 but when I try to apply it on Example 2, data frame it gives me a different output than expectation. Sir, I have updated the question please check it again.

Comment: Example 2 works in pandas 1.2.4  at least with the way you have your dataframe formatted as text. It's possible the underlying types were masked when you called `print`. However, you can try the way the DataFrame example goes `r = df.explode('record')['record'].value_counts()`. Example 2 should be `new_df.explode('teams')['teams'].value_counts()` instead. If that doesn't work you might want to double check the type of values in your dataframe column. Include `new_df.head(5).to_dict()` in your question so that the exact dataframe can be built instead of interpreted from plaintext.